# Remove redundant/duplicate and keep most complete unique records

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark, pyspark

I have table:

| Row | User | Given Name | Family Name | Address | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John | Smith | 1 Main Rd | 1000 |
| 2 | 1 | John |  | 1 Main Rd | 1000 |
| 3 | 1 | John |  |  | 1000 |
| 4 | 1 | John |  |  | 0800 |
| 5 | 1 | Johnny |  |  | 1000 |
| 6 | 2 | Tom | Lock | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 7 | 2 | Tommy |  | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 8 | 2 | Tom | L | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 9 | 2 |  |  |  | 1001 |
| 10 | 3 |  | Oak | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |
| 11 | 3 | Tim |  | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |

I want to be able to remove 'redundant' records - which basically just repeats the same information. In the example above row 2 and row 3 are basically just repeating row 1 (but with additional nulls/blanks) and row 9 is repeating row 6.

So the desired output looks like:

| Row | User | Given Name | Family Name | Address | ZIP |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John | Smith | 1 Main Rd | 1000 |
| 4 | 1 | John |  |  | 0800 |
| 5 | 1 | Johnny |  |  | 1000 |
| 6 | 2 | Tom | Lock | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 7 | 2 | Tommy |  | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 8 | 2 | Tom | L | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 10 | 3 |  | Oak | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |
| 11 | 3 | Tim |  | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |

Looking to do this in either SQL Server (2014)/Spark/Python.

My initial approach was to:

- count of null values of every row
- self join table on User and compare every field (e.g. given name, family name etc)
- tag records where the comparisons are either all invalid (e.g. nulls) and exact
- remove those records tagged

It's sort of like a brute force approach so wondering if there are any better / more efficient way of doing this?

With rows 10 and 11 I want to keep both as the given name and family name are unique and not something that's been repeated which I realized my tagging probably wouldn't work.

Here is the code to create the table:

```
CREATE TABLE user_list (
    rown INT,
    username INT,
    given_name VARCHAR(50),
    family_name VARCHAR(50),
    address VARCHAR(50),
    zip varchar(10)
)

INSERT INTO user_list (rown, username, given_name, family_name, address, zip)
VALUES (1,1,'John', 'Smith', '1 Main Rd', '1000'),
       (2,1,'John', NULL, '1 Main Rd', '1000'),
       (3,1,'John', NULL, NULL, '1000'),
       (4,1,'John', NULL, NULL, '0800'),
       (5,1,'Johnny', NULL, NULL, '1000'),
       (6,2,'Tom', 'Lock', '2 Main Rd', '1001'),
       (7,2,'Tommy', NULL, '2 Main Rd', '1001'),
       (8,2,'Tom', 'L', '2 Main Rd', '1001'),
       (9,2,NULL, NULL, NULL, '1001'),
       (10,3,NULL, 'Oak', '4 Main Rd', '1004'),
       (11,3,'Tim', NULL, '4 Main Rd', '1004');
```

Comment: What version of SQL Server? Run the command `select @@version` and add the result to your post. (SQL Server 2022 has some new functions that may be useful for this task.)

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier for us to assist and test.

Comment: What if 2 rows have the same number of nulls, what takes priority then?

Comment: version 12.0.2000.8 - which I believe SQL Server 2014

Comment: Added the DDL/DML and row 10,11 to the example. If the information is unique and not a repeat, I'd want to keep them both

Comment: Why is this also tagged Spark? That's very different to SQL Server...

Comment: Why aren't rows 10 and 11 collapsed to make a single row for `Tim Oak`, rather than having separate rows for `Tim NULL` and `NULL Oak`?

Comment: @MatBailie one assumes that isn't a certain match.

Comment: thanks for the responses all - both work! I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following will check for matches and exclude the lesser match. In case of an exact match (same value/null combination), the lower rnum row is retrained.

```
WITH CTE_UserList AS (
    -- Calculate number of non-null, non-blank values for each row.
    SELECT
        UL.*,
        CASE WHEN UL.given_name        > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN UL.family_name > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN UL.address     > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            + CASE WHEN UL.zip         > '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            AS ValueCount
    FROM user_list UL
)
SELECT *
FROM CTE_UserList UL
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    -- Find equal or better match
    SELECT *
    FROM CTE_UserList UL2
    WHERE UL2.username = UL.username
    AND ( -- More values is a clear winner. If same values, pick lower rown
        UL2.ValueCount > UL.ValueCount
        OR (UL2.ValueCount = UL.ValueCount AND UL2.rown < UL.rown)
    )
    -- Match on equal or current row value null or blank
    AND (UL2.given_name  = UL.given_name  OR NULLIF(UL.given_name,  '') IS NULL)
    AND (UL2.family_name = UL.family_name OR NULLIF(UL.family_name, '') IS NULL)
    AND (UL2.address     = UL.address     OR NULLIF(UL.address,     '') IS NULL)
    AND (UL2.zip         = UL.zip         OR NULLIF(UL.zip,         '') IS NULL)
)
ORDER BY UL.username, UL.rown
```

Results (with extra data before duplicate elimination)

| rown | username | given_name | family_name | address | zip | ValueCount | CoveredByRow |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John | Smith | 1 Main Rd | 1000 | 4 | null |
| 2 | 1 | John | null | 1 Main Rd | 1000 | 3 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | John | null | null | 1000 | 2 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | John | null | null | 0800 | 2 | null |
| 5 | 1 | Johnny | null | null | 1000 | 2 | null |
| 6 | 2 | Tom | Lock | 2 Main Rd | 1001 | 4 | null |
| 7 | 2 | Tommy | null | 2 Main Rd | 1001 | 3 | null |
| 8 | 2 | Tom | L | 2 Main Rd | 1001 | 4 | null |
| 9 | 2 | null | null | null | 1001 | 1 | 6 |
| 10 | 3 | null | Oak | 4 Main Rd | 1004 | 3 | null |
| 11 | 3 | Tim | null | 4 Main Rd | 1004 | 3 | null |
| 12 | 4 | null | Beam | 4 Main Rd | 1004 | 3 | 14 |
| 13 | 4 | Jim | null | 4 Main Rd | 1004 | 3 | 14 |
| 14 | 4 | Jim | Beam | 4 Main Rd | 1004 | 4 | null |
| 15 | 5 | Exact | Match | null | null | 2 | null |
| 16 | 5 | Exact | Match | null | null | 2 | 15 |

See [this db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/701NgC51) with some extra data showing a few more partial and one exact match.

Answer (score 2):

The following produces the desired results, it uses the `NOT EXISTS` clause to ensure that no similar version of the row, but with more specificity exists. And it uses `ROW_NUMBER()` to reduce any exact duplicates to a single row.

```
with cte as (
  select rown, username, given_name, family_name, address, zip
    , row_number() over (partition by given_name, family_name, address, zip order by rown) rn
  from user_list ul
  where (given_name is not null or family_name is not null)
  and not exists (
    select 1
    from user_list ul1
    where ul.rown <> ul1.rown
    and (ul1.given_name = ul.given_name or (ul.given_name is null and ul1.given_name is not null))
    and (ul1.family_name = ul.family_name or (ul.family_name is null and ul1.family_name is not null))
    and (ul1.address = ul.address or (ul.address is null and ul1.address is not null))
    and ul1.zip = ul.zip
  )
)
select rown, username, given_name, family_name, address, zip
from cte
where rn = 1
order by rown;
```

Returns

| rown | username | given_name | family_name | address | zip |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | John | Smith | 1 Main Rd | 1000 |
| 4 | 1 | John | *null* | *null* | 0800 |
| 5 | 1 | Johnny | *null* | *null* | 1000 |
| 6 | 2 | Tom | Lock | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 7 | 2 | Tommy | *null* | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 8 | 2 | Tom | L | 2 Main Rd | 1001 |
| 10 | 3 | *null* | Oak | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |
| 11 | 3 | Tim | *null* | 4 Main Rd | 1004 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jPew018x)

Comment: If there were two identical rows *(such as in @tn answer)* this would eleminate both?

Comment: @MatBailie no it actually eliminates neither :) but fixed now.